# Using a text file with JSON data and use it in Tkinter

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I have used an API using python, to call out to "NewsAPI" to get all the latest news that I need and I have actually save it into a text file called "NewsAPI.txt".

My code is:

```py
    import json 
    import requests


    def newsAPI():
        url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?' #API URL
               'q=procurement AND tender&' #keywords on procurement AND tender
               'sortBy=popularity&' #Sort them by popularity
               'apiKey=***') #Personal API key

        # GET
        response = requests.get(url)

        #storing the output into variable "results"
        results = response.json()
        # save the JSON output into a txt file for future usage
        with open("NewsAPI.txt", "w") as text_file:
            json.dump(results, text_file)
```

After calling `json.dump`, it gets saved into the "NewsAPI.txt" file as I have mentioned. But I'm having trouble putting it into a treeview in Tkinter, or am I using the wrong widget to display them?

Output data:
[image: Output for the JSON DATA]

Comment: You are displaying the wrong piece of code here - you need to show us what you've done with the tkinter script, and what the expected and actual results are

Comment: That's the code I use to get a text file by using the API. I'm trying to use it in a treeview. Or rather asking for any recommendation that I can use for the data I have by using the API in tkinter.

Ideally, I'm looking at something similar to this. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=json+treeview&sxsrf=ACYBGNQuCeOENdHA3FWqm4xDuzy99jeCFA:1571566151335&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikq72RzKrlAhVq63MBHSNYCaMQ_AUIEigB&biw=1920&bih=920#imgrc=C89Xmaj6Dvb7WM:

Comment: Ok, that's all good, but we need to see the actual tkinter script otherwise we can't help. Also, link/embed that image in your question.

Comment: Hi, I do not have any tkinter script for it, as I don't even know where to begin with on how to do with the data. I'm very new to python. Hence, I don't know what can I do with the API data based on the knowledge I have with python or tkinter.

Comment: Right then. The best thing to do is follow a tutorial (try zetcode.com) for tkinter, which will help you. Then, try and program it, and if it doesn't work, come back here then, and we can help.

Comment: Hi, I actually have went through those tutorials before. My current output for my code above are these. I will placed it in the main question. But I can't put it into a treeview, as I do not know how to implement it. Those tutorials only teach the basics of it. Which I do know how to do it for basics one. But not for JSON datas.

Comment: Have you read the https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html tutorial? Make sure to customise to show only python in the sidebar

Comment: I have read that tutorial before. If you do realize, those are actually trying to teach me how to use on normal datas instead of JSON data. JSON data is slightly trickier. And that Image is the output i have from API. Not my codes. It's the data I have and trying to insert it into treeview.

Comment: The JSON data are a dict, aren't it? If so add each headline as a node, and other information as a subnode.

Comment: Do you have any working example codes of a treeview using node? Because I thought of that theory. However, when I tried to code it out, it doesn't seems to be able to capture the way I want.

Comment: I'll post some code explaining the treeview bit when I have some time to write it. I won't give you a whole script, just the TK part.

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much